# Aurelia - Using variable as name of property in data binding

Tags: javascript, aurelia

Using Aurelia, is it possible to use a variable name to dynamically reference a model object's property name?

Javascript:

```
dow = ['monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday'];
test = {
    monday:     false,
    tuesday:    false,
    wednesday:  false,
    thursday:   false,
    friday:     false,
};
```

HTML:

```
<label repeat.for="day of dow"><input type="checkbox" class="form-control" checked.bind="test[day]" />${day}</label>
```

This results in: "TypeError: obj is undefined"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the Aurelia Docs:

> Each item that is being repeated by the repeat attribute has several
> special contextual values available for binding:
>
> $parent - At present, the main view model's properties and methods are
> not visible from within the repeated item. We hope to remedy this in
> an update soon. For the mean time, you can access that view-model with
> $parent.
>
> $index - The index of the item in the array.
>
> $first - True if the item is the first item in the array.
>
> $last - True if the item is the last item in the array.
>
> $even - True if the item has an even numbered index.
>
> $odd - True if the item has an odd numbered index.

It worked after updating the HTML to reference parent.new_deal[day]:

```html
<label repeat.for="day of dow"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-inline" checked.bind="$parent.new_deal[day]" />${day}</label>
```